# Waypoint jQuery - 2 different offset for up and down roll

Tags: jquery

Why it does not work correctly?
I need to create two different offsets. Small for up and bigest for down scrolling.
This code do not work well.

```
// The same for all waypoints

$('body').delegate('section > article', 'waypoint.reached', function(event, direction) {
    var $active = $(this);

    if (direction === "up") {
        $active = $active.prev();
        $('section > article').waypoint({ offset: '10%' });
    }
    if (!$active.length) $active = $active.end();

            if (direction === "down") {

        $('section > article').waypoint({ offset: '60%' });
    }


    $('.link-active').removeClass('link-active');
    $('a[href=#'+$active.attr('id')+']').addClass('link-active');
});

// Register each section as a waypoint.


$('section > article#p1').waypoint({ offset: '28%' });
$('section > article').waypoint({ offset: '0' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using two waypoints:

```
$('.thing').waypoint(function(direction) {
  if (direction === 'down') {
    // Do stuff
  }
}, {
  offset: '25%'
}).waypoint(function(direction) {
  if (direction === 'up') {
    // Do stuff
  }
}, {
  offset: '75%'
});
```

For futher information take a look at this topic where the master himself answers:

[different offset for jquery waypoint "up" event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181435/different-offset-for-jquery-waypoint-up-event)